# Time series and first order difference correlation coefficient to adjust for autocorrelation

Tags: time-series, correlation, data-transformation, autocorrelation

I have come across an adjustment method that uses the correlation coefficient and a first difference to adjust for autocorrelation in a times series. All data points transformed using the formula:

$
y_{t}=\frac{x_{t} -\rho x_{t-1}}{1-\rho} 
$

where $\rho$ is the correlation coefficient between $x_{t}$ and $x_{t-1}$

Can anyone guide me to the theory behind this transformation method for autocorrelation/stationarity and how the $1-\rho$ enters the denominator ?

Thank you
Christian